# How to surround image tag with div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag that contains inner div tag tags. How can I add open and close tag around the x number of div tags.

E.x.

```
    <div id="resizable">
        <div><img class="img1 image" src="images/lion5.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion1.jpg"/></div>
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion2.jpg"/></div>
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion3.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
```

Add transform the codes into:

```
<div id="resizable">
    <div class="row">
        <div><img class="img1 image" src="images/lion5.jpg" /></div>
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion1.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion2.jpg"/></div>
        <div><img class="img2 image" src="images/lion3.jpg"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope anyone can tell me a script to do this dynamically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Completing @Derek answer, you can loop aroud a [.slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) and use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to finish the work.

```
var c = $('#resizable').children();

for (var i = 0 ; i < c.length ; i+=2) {
    c.slice(i,i+2).wrapAll('<div class="row"></div>');
}​
```

Demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/SAtrc/1/

Comment: Completely forgot about `wrapAll()`... Nice one!

Comment: nice - way more elegant than my solution

Comment: Wow, totally forgot about `warpAll`... @Edesa, if you think Artimuz's answer solves your problem, you can `check it as the solution`.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/ - Examples and usage included.

Comment: Don't think `wrap` can help with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence I'd probably use is first, insert the first div.row into the div#resizable, then start moving the inner divs you want into that div. Then, append another div.row and move the remaining inner divs into that one. Working on a fiddle to demonstrate, but this is the way I'd attack it.

here's the jsfiddle that does it: http://jsfiddle.net/rsPGv/

```
var $firstDiv = $('<div />').prependTo('div#resizable').addClass('row');
$('div div:nth-child(2)').appendTo($firstDiv);
$('div div:nth-child(2)').appendTo($firstDiv);
var $secondDiv = $('<div />').insertAfter($firstDiv).addClass('row');
$('div div:nth-child(3)').appendTo($secondDiv);
$('div div:nth-child(3)').appendTo($secondDiv);
```

You'll need to inspect the DOM through firebug or web dev tools to see the updated DOM. The code isn't very DRY and could undoubtedly be refactored to be more elegant, but this does accomplish the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to select each child element of a parent element and then wrap them with any tag you want:

```
$('div.row > img').wrap('<div></div>');
```

You can refer these links if you need further clarification:

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/wrap/